# Akeeba Kickstart with Joomla 2.5.13 throws 403 Error

Tags: joomla2.5

Everytime I start to extract my Akeeba Backup, I get a 403 error and an Uncaught ReferenceError as such

> POST http://maxnathaniel.com/joomla/kickstart.php 403 (Forbidden)
>   kickstart.php:1119 Uncaught ReferenceError: Response is not defined

Versions

1. Joomla - 2.5.13
2. Akeeba Kickstart - 4.0.0

File Permissions

1. Joomla subdirectory folder is on 755
2. Files within the joomla folder is 644

Included in my /public_html/joomla are en-GB.kickstart.ini, index.html (a sample index file), kickstart.php and my backup file in .jpa format (file size is 1GB).

Appreciate any help, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Akeeba Kickstart, I used Akeeba eXtract Wizard. Unpacked the .jpa file on my local machine, and uploaded it via FTP to my server. It worked without any problems.